# PHP inside echo HTML?

Tags: conditional-tags

I am a little bit confused about the following code:

```
<?php
if (is_home() ) {
echo '<div id="bg" style="background:url("assets/img/header_1.jpg");">';
} else ( is_page( 52 )) {
echo '<div id="bg" style="background:url("assets/img/header_2.jpg");">';
}
?>
```

It is supposed to change the header background for different pages.

The code itself works, because CSS classes were imported correctly.
Unfortunately "/assets/..." doesn't work so I suppose I need this function:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>
```

How can I implement it properly inside echo?

Comment: Try giving full url path for image rather than relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings with the result of a php function:

```
echo '<div id="bg" style="background:url(' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/header_2.jpg);">';
```

Codex: [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

However, it doesn't work.
When I do this with CSS class, everything works great:

    `<?php
    if (is_front_page() ) {
    echo '<div id="bg" class="header-bg-mainpage">';`

CSS:
    `.header-bg-mainpage {background:url("assets/img/header_1.jpg") no-repeat center center;}`

What function should I use then to get the directory and use *.jpg not through CSS?

Comment: @Dandy, try using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead

Comment: also doesn't work. I don't get it why in CSS file simple directory "assets/.."  works and in header.php file not. These two files are in the same folder.

Comment: to the frontend, it is probably checking for the example.com/assets/.. when you're on the homepage. open the devtools and see the path. I've tried the code above and i got the right path. A link to your site would help debugging.

Comment: you're right! i forgot the double quotes.. :/ it was closing the style attributes.

Comment: I've just deleted double quotes from url("") and now it works. I thought that url goes always with double quotes inside of (). Well, thank you for your help, now everything works well!